# Problems with passing data from view to template?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am new to Django Python and I am learning how to use Django and passing data from view to template. Now, here is my situation and I really need some help in understanding where i can be doing wrong.

I am trying to pass data from view to template and then parse the object in the view but for some reason nothing is happening in the template. I have printed the registration object in my views.py and it works fine and displays the information that is correct. But when I send the registration object from views to template nothing happens.

**models.py**

```
    from django.db import models

    from datetime import datetime
    from django.shortcuts import redirect

    # Create your models here.

    # Create your models here.

    class Registration(models.Model):
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
        email = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
        password = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
        mobilenumber = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
        created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

        class Meta:

            ordering = ('first_name',)
```

**views.py**

```
    class Loginview(CreateView):
        model = Registration
        form_class = LoginForm
        template_name = "loginvalentis/valentis_login.html"

        def get(self, request):
            form = LoginForm()

            # returning form
            return render(request, 'loginvalentis/valentis_login.html', {'form': form});

        def form_valid(self,form):
            user_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            user_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            try:
                registration = Registration.objects.get(email=user_email)
                print ("registration",registration.mobilenumber)




                return redirect('/loginvalentis/home/',{'registration':registration})

            except Registration.DoesNotExist:
                user_info = None
                return redirect('/loginvalentis/login/')
```

**Template result.html --- ('/loginvalentis/home/')**

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="form1">
    {% csrf_token %}
<div>
    hello world
    <form id ="form1">
        <ul>
  {% for user in registration %}
    <li>{{ user.mobilenumber }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
    </form>
</div>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the problem you re having is with the home view, then you need to post that view, not the apparently-irrelevant login view.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the `redirect()` function. You are trying to pass the `registration` object through it, but it doesn't support this, it's *args and **kwargs are simply a parameters for reversing the url, see here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.redirect

You should use some other way to pass it to another view, e.g. pass only it's id as a parameter of that view's url (you will have to change the url conf appropriatelly), the other way is to use sessions etc.

see:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/

But really, it would be **much easier for you** just to walk through this tutorial very carefully 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/ trust me, it will be **really worth your time**, because from your question I can easily tell that you just don't understand what you are doing.